# How to run a powerShell script from a python file

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I couldn't find much information on this unfortunately, but I wish to run a powerShell script from a python file I've written. I want the user to actually see the powerShell script being run and the user can enter inputs that the powerShell script requires from python. I am using pyCharm as an IDE.

When I run the script to call this powerShell script, it gives me this error:

```
File "C:\TestAutomation\eFuse\eFuse.ps1", line 19
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file C:\Test\eK\eK.ps1 on line 19, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
        elif switch_result == "eTool":
            subprocess.call(['python', 'C:\\TestAutomation\\eFuse\\eFuse.ps1'], stdout=sys.stdout)
```

This elif statement is a part of other if/elif statements that run other python files using the subproccess module, but for some reason I can't get this powerShell file to be run. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, you should already know `.py` file's interpreter is `python.exe`

So, it's easy to understand `.ps1` file's interpreter is `powershell.exe`, not `python.exe`

I just copy & paste from yours, your code should look like following,

```
subprocess.call('powershell.exe -File "C:\\TestAutomation\\eFuse\\eFuse.ps1"', stdout=sys.stdout)
```

Details about `powershell.exe -?`

Comment: thanks a lot. Your way worked but the only problem is that it is not outputting everything that would appear when you run the script. For example, I built a program that has a menu of things. When the user selects this powershell script, it does not print the beginning of the powershell script, it only prints the error when the user picks something wrong in the script. How can output everything the powershell file outputs onto the console ?

Comment: @SaturnsBelt Please post an example here. A simple one plz.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following for provide input from user to PS (powershell) script from python :

**1) Create parameterised powershell script**

**2) Take input in python and set it as PS script parameter.**

**3) run/execute the script with given params.**

Here is the sample to run powershell script from python with param. Its a python code :

*** Hope you have the PS script with parameters.**

```
import subprocess

params = ['param1', 'param2']  # POWERSHELL SCRIPT PARAMETERS ( optional )
script_path = "C:\\PowershellScripts\\test.PS1"  # POWERSHELL SCRIPT PATH
commandline_options = ["Powershell.exe", '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', script_path]  # INITIALIZING COMMAND
for param in params:  # FOREACH LOOP OF PARAMETERS
    commandline_options.append(param)  # ADDING SCRIPT PARAMETERS TO THE COMMAND

result = subprocess.run(commandline_options, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)  # RUN THE SCRIPT USING SUBPROCESS WITH PARAMS

print(result.returncode)  # PRINT THE RETURN CODE FROM POWERSHELL SCRIPT
print(result.stdout)  # PRINT THE STANDARD OUTPUT FROM POWERSHELL SCRIPT
print(result.stderr)  # PRINT THE STANDARD ERROR FROM POWERSHELL SCRIPT
```

You can see the output of python if it exist ( if there is no error in powershell script. you will not get any output from last line )